# New to async programming. How do I get things to happen in proper sequence across different objects?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to refactor my program. I had made it work by making the AJAX calls synchronous, but now I'd like to do it the proper way. What's happening is that `headline` is instantiated with a new headline from `headlines` which contains a list of headlines. `headlines.getRandom()` selects a random headline from the existing list, but, if the list is empty, it makes an AJAX call to fetch more headlines.

I can't quite wrap my head around how to make the `Headline` object constructor wait for the call to complete without making the two objects interdependent. As it stands, the headline fails to be instantiated because it's trying to instantiate from an object that is undefined since the call hasn't successfully completed.

I know about callbacks, but how can I use callbacks to cause one object to wait on the success of an AJAX call from another without getting into a lot of object incest?

```
headline = new Headline(headlines.getRandom(true));
fillHeadline();
```

Here's the code in context if you'd like to look at more of it.
https://github.com/raddevon/onion-or-not/blob/true-ajax/js/js.js#L104

Comment: This should give you some good ideas of what is possible: https://github.com/caolan/async/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides callbacks, that you already mention. You can use `deferred` objects and `promises`.
For example, with [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

There are a few advantages of using deferred/promises instead of callbacks:

- Promises can be chained, it is possible to wait for several promises before doing something, e.g jQuery.when() . With callbacks is a bit more messy.
- You can check the state of the promise, for example to display an initial default value while waiting for the actual data.
- It is easier to decouple the *producer* and the *consumer* of the data. Promises are returned and passed along in procedural/sync style (as if they were the actual data), This  helps in avoiding complicated chains of callbacks in which the execution path would be hard to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using jQuery, I'd look into jQuery promises. You can find decent introductions at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises/ and http://eng.wealthfront.com/2012/12/jquerydeferred-is-most-important-client.html.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a couple of things that are asynchronous in JavaScript:

- Event listeners
- `setTimeout`
- `setInterval`

AJAX uses event listeners internally.

So you do someting like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
xhr.addEventlistener('readystatechanged', function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

If you're working with a callback your code could look something like this:

```
function do_ajax(url, data, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.addEventlistener('readystatechanged', function () {
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

do_ajax("service.php", "foo=bar", function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

---

If you have very complex asynchronous processes I recommend taking a look at [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A). [Here is jQuery's take on promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

You can do something like:

```
when(async_process()).then(function (result) {
    return do_something_asynchronous(result); // <-- the result is a promise
}).done(function (result) { // <--  and the resolved value is the input here
    console.log(result);
});
```

With Promises your code could look like:

```
headlines.getRandom(true).then(function (random_headlines) {
    return new HeadLine(random_headlines);
}).done(headline) {
    console.log("And presto!", headline);
});
```

Comment: Since @raddevon is using jQuery, there's no need to go this low-level and deal with XMLHTTPRequest directly. jQuery provides higher-level tools that will accomplish this better.

Comment: If I don't expose ajax internals you can't actually see the event listener at work.

Answer (score 0):

breaking the ajax concept a bit, I would try:

```
...
this.refreshContent = function() {
        // Reloads JSON file
        $.ajax(this.url, {

            async: false,

            success: this.fillFromJSON.bind(this),
...
```